# e4: dependency injection and disposing widgets

Tags: java, dependency-injection, swt, rcp, e4

I have got some instances of a class which is derived from an `SWT` `Composite`.
These instances are injected with `ContextInjectionFactory`. An example of the class would be:

```
public class MyTest extends Composite {
    public MyTest(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
    }

    @Inject
    @Optional
    private void doSomething(@UIEventTopic(EventConstants.TEST) Object unused) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

And this is how I use it:

```
public createTestContent() {
    MyTest myTest = new MyTest(composite, SWT.NONE);
    ContextInjectionFactory.inject(myTest, context);
}

public someAction() {
    composite.dispose();
}
```

If I dispose off these objects now (by disposing their parent), I would expect that the method doSomething from the example code is not called anymore. But in fact it will still be called.

In order to stop this behavior I need to call

```
ContextInjectionFactory.uninject(myTest, context);
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Injection is not connected with SWT and vice versa. You can inject any objects, even disposed widgets.

Comment: @Mr Covex Okay, that makes sense. So this is a problem of garbage collection? During testing, I observed that only a limited number of disposed widgets will react to events.

Comment: If they are in the context, they cannot be garbage collected. More code is needed to understand your situation.

Comment: @Mr Covex the objects are not in the context, they are just injected. Please refer to my edited post.

Comment: If they are injected, they are in the context: http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/tutorials/eclipse-4-e4-tutorial-part-4-dependency-injection-basics/

Comment: @Mr Covex okay if they are really present in the context, why are they garbage collected at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `@UIEventTopic` Eclipse has to remember the method so that it can call it whenever an event occurs. Eclipse continues to remember and call this method until you run `ContextInjectionFactory.uninject` on the class instance.

This has nothing to do with disposing of SWT controls - that just releases any native data being used by the controls.

It looks like the `ExtendedObjectSupplier` which deals with `@UIEventTopic` uses a `WeakReference` to remember the method information so the data may sometimes be disposed when memory is tight.